# iPhone - in-app purchase dumbness

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have this app setup with in-app purchase.

If I am logged in on iTunes with my regular account, when I run the app and tap to buy an item in my app, it works, it asks me if I really wan to buy the item for X dollars bla bla bla... if I proceed it will probably buy it.

but, if I log out from my regular iTunes account and run my app again, it fails before asking me if I want to buy the in-app.

So, it is not a matter of user or certificates. It is a sandbox problem. You see, it doesn't even asks me if I want to buy the product, that is a screen before you type the user credentials. It fails with "cannot connect to iTunes store" error... !!!

Any clues of what may be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cannot connect to iTunes store -1003 is a common error.
1) Reset your Network Settings on your device and try again.
2) Create a new test user account (This might not be useful in your case, since it throws error even before login)

Comment: I did that again. No change. As I said, the error precedes any credential dialog. The network is working, as it is able to buy using my regular itunes account, but as soon as I log out, the sandbox is never able to contact iTunes for buying. On the other hand, the sandbox is able to retrieve the products and its prices. The problem appears to be with what happens after  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an account how you are able to buy an application? the application checks first in itunes account. so its compulsory for you to be logged in in itunes when the in app purchase executes. this is not an error. It is a feature provided by apple.

Comment: it never asks for credentials. So, it is not a feature.